# Duda sobre recursividad que llama dos veces a la misma función

Tags: c++

No se por qué, en una función recursiva, a veces se ha de llamar dos veces la misma función para realizar cualquier acción.

Por ejemplo aquí:

```
int operacion (){
  char e;
  cin >> e;
  if(e  >= '0' and e <= '9') return  e - '0';
  else{
    int x = operacion(); // <<--- AQUI
    int y = operacion();
    if( e == '+') return (x + y);
    else if( e== '-') return (x - y);
    else return (x * y);
  }  
}
```

¿No se supone que cuando llega a `int x=operacion()`, se ignora todo lo que sigue después de esta línea?

Comment: Te recomiendo poner el código, como lo que es, no se si sepas hacerlo, pero edita la pregunta, y selecciona el código y dale click a las llaves que ves en la parte de arriba para las opciones del texto. De esta forma ayudas al que va responder poder ver mejor la pregunta.

Comment: *¿No se supone que cuando llega a int x=operacion(), se ignora todo lo que sigue después de esta línea?* La respuesta es: "No necesariamente.", a no ser que quieras hacer un Stack Overflow. En tu caso la recursividad puede que no vaya a parar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, la sentencia recursiva (la que llama a la `operacion` de nuevo), es una sentencia más. Se ejecuta, se completa, y el código continúa:

```
// Llamamos a operación desde el `main()` y comienza la recursión
val = int operacion() // y el usuario escribe un +
   int x = operacion() // y el usuario escribe un +
      int x = operacion() // y el usuario escribe un 2
         return 2;
      int y = operacion() // y el usuario escribe un *
         int x = operacion() // y el usuario escribe un 4
             return 4;
         int y = operacion() // y el usuario escribe un 8
             return 8;
         return 4*8;
      return 2 + 32;
   int y = operacion() // y el usuario escribe un -
      int x = operacion() // y el usuario escribe un 6
         return 6;
      int y = operacion() // y el usuario escribe un 8
         return 8;
      return 6-8;
   return 34-2;

// val <- 32
```

Y por tanto, la función recursiva devuelve el valor 32 con esa hipotética secuencia de valores introducidos por el usuario.

Answer (score 4):

Una función recursiva tiene varias características.

1. Se invoca a sí misma, con un tamaño de problema menor (por tamaño de problema debe entenderse una solución mucho más sencilla que el problema original).
2. Debe converger a un caso base, es decir, dado un problema lo suficientemente pequeño la función debe retornar de forma apropiada la solución.

A partir de lo que puedo leer de su código entiendo que intenta realizar una función que capture dos números (operandos) y un operador +, -, *) y a partir de esa información retorne la operación de aplicar el operador a los operandos ingresados. No es habitual usar recursividad en este problema, porque no hay un 'problema' que se pueda resolver de forma más sencilla a partir del problema original usando recursividad.

Tan pronto la función recursiva llega al caso base (es decir, retorna un resultado en vez de llamarse a sí misma de nuevo) el código que la llamó continúa su ejecución en la siguiente línea. Esto quiere decir que en estas dos líneas de la función operacion()

```
int x = operacion();
int y = operacion();
```

tan pronto se retorne del nuevo llamado a operacion() y se asigne un valor a la variable x, la función volverá a llamarse a sí misma y el resultado de su ejecución se almacenará en la variable y. Esto sucederá sí y solo sí el método llega a retornar algún valor base (si el caracter ingresado es un dígito del 0 al 9, o los operadores +, -, *), en cuyo caso sí se ignora el resto del código porque de forma explícita la palabra clave return indica eso: devuelva el resultado y termine la ejecución de la función.